# How to search on part of element name + variable

Tags: jquery

I can search all id's using the start of a variable name:

> **"month2015Jan"**  (one of the id's)
>
> **"month2015Feb"**  (one of the id's)

```
$('[id^="month"]').prop('disabled', false)
```

But I want to also use a variable for the year:

```
KEYyear = "2015"
```

I've tried:

```
$('[id^="month" + KEYyear]').prop('disabled', false)
$('[id^="month"]'+ KEYyear).prop('disabled', false)
$('[id^="month"] + KEYyear').prop('disabled', false)
```

Nothing works.  Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct approach: `$('[id^="month' + KEYyear + '"]')`, or, to make it more explicit:

```
var idPattern = 'month' + KEYyear; // What you're looking for
var jqPattern = '[id^="' + idPattern + '"]'; // What the selector looks like
$(jqPattern)...
```

Your first pattern was almost correct, but it was looking for `"month"2015` instead of `"month2015"`

Answer (score 1):

You've just to concatenate it with the `month` string using `+` sign, like :

```
var KEYyear = "2015";
$('[id^="month' + KEYyear + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

That will return all the elements with `id`'s start with `month2015` in this case.

Hope this helps.